# Compute $\int\frac {x^2}{x^4+1}dx$ via partial fractions

Tags: calculus, integration, systems-of-equations, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

I am trying to solve it with "partial fractions"

$$\frac {x^2}{x^4+1}=\frac{x^2}{(x^2+x\sqrt{2}+1)(x^2-x\sqrt{2}+1)}=\frac{Ax+B}{(x^2+x\sqrt{2}+1)}+\frac{Cx+D}{(x^2-x\sqrt{2}+1)}$$

and I get the following system of equations:

$A+C=0$

$-\sqrt{2}A+B+\sqrt{2}C+D=1$

$A-\sqrt{2}B+C+\sqrt{2}D=0$

$B+D=0$

How can I find $A,B,C,D$?

Comment: It's a pretty standard system of linear equations, you could use, for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination

Comment: @MattiP.  Is it possible to solve every system of equations  with Gaussian elimination
method? I am not familiar with solving system of equations

Comment: How did you get $A+C=1$?  Multiplying both sides by $x$ and then taking $x\to \infty$, you obtain $A+C=0$.

Comment: @Soheil Every _linear_ system of equations, yes.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool thanks it is typo i fixed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Observe that the integrand is an even fraction, so it is invariant when we change $x$ to $-x$: 
$$\frac{Ax+B}{(x^2+x\sqrt{2}+1)}+\frac{Cx+D}{(x^2-x\sqrt{2}+1)}=\frac{-Ax+B}{(x^2-x\sqrt{2}+1)}+\frac{-Cx+D}{(x^2+x\sqrt{2}+1)}.$$
This implies that $\;C=-A,\; D=B$, and  you have only a linear system in two unknowns.

Comment: Nice trick :) ${}$

Answer (score 2):

From $A+C=0$ and $A-B\sqrt2+C+D\sqrt2=0$
we have $$-B\sqrt2+D\sqrt2=0$$
which with $B+D=0$, gives $B=D=0$.

Now from $A+C=0$ and $-A\sqrt2+B+C\sqrt2+D=1$, noting that $B=D=0$, we have
$$A=-C\implies C\sqrt2+C\sqrt{2}=1\implies C=\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}$$
and $$A=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}$$

Answer (score 2):

You can solve the (easy) $4\times4$ system of linear equations, but notice that

$$(x^2+\sqrt2 x+1)-(x^2-\sqrt2 x+1)=2\sqrt2x$$ so that

$$\frac x{2\sqrt2}\frac{(x^2+\sqrt2 x+1)-(x^2-\sqrt2 x+1)}{(x^2+\sqrt2 x+1)(x^2-\sqrt2 x+1)}$$ does the trick.

---

Notice that this will work for any positive power of $x$ at the numerator, hence any polynomial. Anyway, the constant term requires an extra twist:

$$(x^2+\sqrt2 x+1)+(x^2-\sqrt2 x+1)=2x^2+2,$$ from which you can cancel out $2x^2$.