# Why it is important to write a function as sum of even and odd functions?

Tags: calculus, even-and-odd-functions

For the function $f(x)$ we can write it as sum of even and odd functions:

$$f(x)=\underbrace{\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}}_{\text{Even}}+\underbrace{\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}}_{\text{Odd}}$$

My question is why it is important for us to write a function as sum of these two even and odd functions? Is there any application of that?

Comment: I think it may be useful in calculating definite integral.

Comment: I recently came across this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h7apO7q16V0&ab_channel=Reducible (the FFT algorithm), where even and oddness played a fundamental role. Perhaps it's too advanced for you for now, but the key reason why they were useful was because even and oddness both are a very special kind of symmetry, and the algorithm uses this symmetry to reduce the amount of work by HALF!

Comment: What book are you referring too @Soheil? These are some nice tricks that one doesn't see often

Comment: @Buraian: This is a well know equation in calculus I saw it in my notes and also in some of my translated books.

Comment: @soheil but which books? Perhaps it's well known but I'm asking because I've never seen it before

Comment: @Buraian As I said most books I am reading are not in English so it is hard to gice you name of the books! To study more about it simply search "write a function as sum of even and odd fubctions" also on MSE you can see many question about that. like this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5274/how-do-i-divide-a-function-into-even-and-odd-sections

Comment: @soheil perhaps I am misunderstood. I do not mean to research on this one particular trick as I have understood it already but to learn more of those which are like this. 

You told me your books were translated, if it is so, then I am asking what books were they translated from?

Perhaps books having these tricks are as common as you say it is but unfortunately, I have not found a single one showing tricks as such in my calculus journey.

Comment: To be more clear, I am not asking more about this particular trick but about tricks of like. @soheil

Comment: @Buraian I am not familiar with such books that contain calculus tricks. I myself try learning tricks by reading some elegant answers on this site and get idea from them (for example I learned how even functions would help to decompose a fraction by Bernard's answer on the question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3615427/compute-int-frac-x2x41dx-via-partial-fractions.) maybe other user have more experience about it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3280498/use-of-the-fact-that-every-function-is-sum-of-an-odd-and-an-even-function

Comment: did you just forget the fast fourier transform my dude

Answer (score 122, accepted):

When I was a high school student I thought that the even/odd decomposition you write about seemed kind of peculiar and not so fundamental. After learning more mathematics I realized the method behind it (extracting "symmetric pieces" by averaging and what you might call anti-averaging) is actually a very simple example of two important processes in mathematics: eigenspace decompositions and averaging over a group to extract symmetric pieces of a function (or vector, *etc.*).  What I write below is not meant to give you new situations where your even/odd decomposition helps solve a calculus problem, but to show you many further examples of the same idea so you see it is quite broadly occurring in mathematics.

In nearly every situation where there is an operation that *iterates twice to be the identity operation* you get an analogue of the even/odd decomposition. Here are three examples.

1. The matrix transpose (where $M^{\top\top} = M$) leads to the expression of a square matrix as a sum of matrices that are symmetric ($M^\top = M$) and skew-symmetric ($M^\top = -M$)
   $$
   A = \frac{A + A^\top}{2} + \frac{A - A^\top}{2}
   $$
2. Complex conjugation (where $\overline{\overline{z}} = z$) gives an "even/odd" type viewpoint on writing a complex number in standard form is $a+bi$, since this is the sum of a
   real number (fitting $\overline{w} = w$) and a purely imaginary number (fitting $\overline{w} = -w$):
   $$
   z = \frac{z + \overline{z}}{2} + \frac{z - \overline{z}}{2} = a + bi
   $$
   where $z = a + bi$ and $\overline{z} = a - bi$.
3. The swap operator on functions ($f(x,y) \mapsto f(y,x)$) or tensors ($v \otimes w \mapsto w \otimes v$) leads to the expression of a function or tensor as a sum of symmetric and antisymmetric functions or tensors:
   $$
   f(x,y) = \frac{f(x,y) + f(y,x)}{2} + \frac{f(x,y) - f(y,x)}{2}
   $$
   and
   $$
   v \otimes w = \frac{v \otimes w + w \otimes v}{2} + \frac{v \otimes w - w \otimes v}{2}.
   $$
   This has a role in quantum mechanics, where it underlies the distinction between bosons (having symmetric wavefunctions) and fermions (having antisymmetric wavefunctions).

I said that in *nearly* every situation you get something like an even/odd decomposition because sometimes one of those parts is zero and thus uninteresting.  For instance, a 180-degree rotation $R$ of the plane has $R(v) = -v$ for all $v$ in $\mathbf R^2$, so here the whole space "looks odd" under the effect of $R$.  No vector in $\mathbf R^2$ is fixed by a 180-degree rotation except for the origin.

The use of "order $2$" here keeps the algebra very simple, but we  can also consider *higher-order* symmetries rather than symmetries of order 2.  Consider for each $n \geq 1$ trying to decompose a function $f:\mathbf C \to \mathbf C$ as a sum of functions $f_k(z)$ that get scaled by the $k$th power of each $n$th root of unity when it undergoes interior scaling by each $n$th root of unity: $f_k(\zeta z) = \zeta^k f_k(z)$ for all $n$th roots of unity $\zeta$ (or equivalently just $\zeta = e^{2\pi i/n}$) and all complex numbers $z$, where $0 \leq k \leq n-1$. The case $n=2$ is even/odd functions on $\mathbf C$ ($f_0(-z) = f_0(z)$ means $f_0$ is an even function and $f_1(-z) = -f_1(z)$ means $f_1$ is an odd function).  Taking $n = 4$, we can try to decompose each function  $f:\mathbf C \to \mathbf C$  as a sum of four functions
$$
f(z) = f_0(z) + f_1(z) + f_2(z) + f_3(z)
$$
where $f_0(iz) = f_0(z)$, $f_1(iz) = if_1(z)$, $f_2(iz) = -f_2(z)$, and $f_3(iz) = -if_3(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbf C$.Here are formulas for each of the functions:
$$
f_0(z) = \frac{f(z) + f(iz) + f(-z) + f(-iz)}{4}, 
$$
$$
f_1(z) = \frac{f(z) - if(iz) - f(-z) + if(-iz)}{4},
$$
$$
f_2(z) = \frac{f(z) - f(iz) + f(-z) - f(-iz)}{4},
$$
$$
f_3(z) = \frac{f(z) + if(iz) - f(-z) - if(-iz)}{4}.
$$
These averaging formulas are generalizations of the formulas you wrote for determining the even/odd parts of a function $\mathbf R \to \mathbf R$. And this is useful in Fourier analysis, since the Fourier transform on functions has order $4$.

The ideas presented here extend even further to the decomposition of a representation of a finite group as a sum of irreducible representations. For the cyclic group of order $2$ there are two irreducible representations, and that is reflected in the appearance of even functions and odd functions in your formula. So the even/odd decomposition for functions in your question is a special case of a really important idea in math. It is not just some "trick" to solve artificial calculus problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but these are all about advanced math and I don't know about them unfortunately.

Comment: Please indicate in your question what your math background is if you want to get answers targeted to what you know now as opposed to what you may learn in the future if you go further in math.

Comment: @KCd could you explain what a higher-order symmetry is? I found your answer fascinating but I am not familiar with all the terminology used.

Comment: @Buraian a higher-order symmetry is one that has to be iterated more than twice to return to the identity (fixing everything).  While sending $x$ to $-x$ has order 2, sending $x$ to $ix$ has order 4, because repeated multiplication has the effect $x \leadsto ix \leadsto -x \leadsto -ix \leadsto x$, so (for nonzero $x$) we return to $x$ only after 4 iterations of this operation.

Comment: @KCd This question of mine, and Moishe Kohan's answer, are very much in the spirit of your answer here.  I thought you might enjoy it:

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/755402/34287

Comment: @StevenGubkin that reminds me of Goodman's answer at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79907, which notes that a complex inner product $h \colon V \times V \to \mathbf C$ has a unique decomposition as $g + i\omega$ where $g$ is a real inner product on $V$ s.t. $g(cv,w) = g(v,\overline{c}w)$ for $c \in \mathbf C$, $\omega$ is a nondeg. alt. bil. form on $V$ (as a real v. space) s.t. $\omega(cv,w) = \omega(v,\overline{c}w)$ for $c \in \mathbf C$, and $g$, $\omega$ are linked by the relation $\omega(v,w) = g(v,iw)$ for all $v, w \in V$.  Any of $h$, $g$, or $\omega$ determines the (contd.)

Comment: other two.  Oh, also we need $\omega(iv,v) \geq 0$ for all $v$ with equality if and only if $v = 0$. That's what $g$ being positive-definite means in terms of $\omega$.  So the three pieces of information on $V$ that are equivalent are (i) a complex inner product $h$, (ii) a real inner product $g$ on $V$ such that $g(cv,w) = g(v,\overline{c}w)$ for all $c \in \mathbf C$,and (iii) a nondegenerate alternating bilinear form $\omega$ on $V$ such that $\omega(cv,w) = \omega(v,\overline{c}w)$ and $\omega(iv,v) \geq 0$ for all $v$ with equality if and only if $v = 0$.

Comment: This is a wonderful answer, but it's not clear to me why the order is important.  Could you maybe explain the why/how of this?  Your examples are great, but it's not clear to me what role, if any, the "order 2" property plays.

Comment: @Galendo the second half of the answer discusses higher-order analogues. All the ideas for order 2 extend to higher order situations, but the math can get more complicated (notationally and technically), particularly when the symmetries do not commute with each other (e.g., representations of nonabelian groups rather than cyclic groups).

Comment: @KCd: Maybe I wasn't clear.  You say "In nearly every situation where there is an operation that iterates twice to be the identity operation you get an analogue of the even/odd decomposition", but the connection between a function having order two and a resulting interesting decomposition is unclear.  Is there an interesting decomposition associated with rotation by 180 degrees, for instance?  That has order two, so should I expect an interesting even/odd decomposition result?  Why or why not?

Comment: @Galendo  If $R \colon \mathbf R^n \to \mathbf R^n$ is linear with order 2 then for each $v \in \mathbf R^n$ we can write $v = (v + R(v))/2 + (v - R(v))/2$, which expresses $v$ as a sum $v_1 + v_2$ where $R(v_1) = v_1$ and $R(v_2) = -v_2$.  The "catch" in the example where $R$ is a 180 degree rotation is that $R(v) = -v$ for *all* $v$, so then $v_1 = (v + R(v))/2 = (v-v)/2 = 0$ and thus the decomposition is silly because one of the parts (the $v_1$ part) is always 0.  You always get a decomposition into a $(+1)$-eigenspace and $(-1)$-eigenspace, but here the $(-1)$-eigenspace is everything.

Comment: @Galendo I added that example to the main body of the answer.

Answer (score 61):

One really neat application for this decomposition (which I saw on the YouTube channel "Flammable Maths") is evaluating integrals of the form $$\int_{-a}^a\Bigg(\frac{E(x)}{1+t^{O(x)}}\Bigg)dx$$ where $t,a>0$ are constants, $E(x)$ is a (continuous) even function, and $O(x)$ is a (continuous) odd function. If you set $f(x)=\frac{E(x)}{1+t^{O(x)}}$ and write $$f(x)=\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}+\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}$$ you can say that $$\int_{-a}^a\Bigg(\frac{E(x)}{1+t^{O(x)}}\Bigg)dx=\int_{-a}^a\Bigg(\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}\Bigg)dx+\int_{-a}^a\Bigg(\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}\Bigg)dx$$ The last integral on the RHS vanishes since we're integrating an odd function on a symmetric domain. With a little algebra $\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}E(x)$ giving us the awesome result $$\int_{-a}^a\frac{E(x)}{1+t^{O(x)}}dx=\int_{0}^aE(x)dx$$ which is really cool! This means we can say something like $$\int_{-1}^1\Bigg(\frac{x^4-x^2+1}{1+3^{\sin^2(x)\tan(x)+x^5+x}}\Bigg)dx=\int_0^1\big(x^4-x^2+1\big)dx=\frac{13}{15}$$ This can also be used to calculate some pretty nasty double integrals! $$\int_0^1 \int_{-x^2}^{x^2}\Bigg(\frac{xy^2+x^3}{1+3^{x\tan^{11}(y)+e^x\sin^7(y)}}\Bigg)dydx=\int_0^1 \int_0^{x^2}(xy^2+y^3)dydx=\frac{5}{24}$$ Love it.

**Edit**: This integration technique actually generalizes to integrals of the form $$\int_{-a}^a\Bigg(\frac{E_1(x)}{1+\big(E_2(x)\big)^{O(x)}}\Bigg)dx$$ where $E_1(x),E_2(x)$ are arbitrary (continuous) even functions while $O(x)$ is an arbitrary (continuous) odd function. Using the exact same procedure delineated above we can say $$\int_{-a}^a\Bigg(\frac{E_1(x)}{1+\big(E_2(x)\big)^{O(x)}}\Bigg)dx=\int_{0}^aE_1(x)dx$$ which means $$\int_{-1}^1\Bigg(\frac{x^4+x^2+1}{1+\big(x^2e^{-x^4}+\cos(x)\sin(x^2)\big)^{x^2\tan(x^3)+x}}\Bigg)dx=\int_0^1(x^4+x^2+1)dx=\frac{23}{15}$$

Comment: I was really confused by your notation, because I was reading $e(x)$ as $\exp(x)$ and couldn't understand why $e^x$ was even. Also, didn't grasp the $o$ in your denominator as a function, despite the text. Even though the definitions in your description are unambiguous, I think it costs some brain power to parse. (Disclaimer: I'm no mathematician.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I just borrowing the notation from the video in which I saw this application. I will change my presentation to avoid further complications of this sort.

Comment: I confirm that it is less confusing with capital letters. (Missed one in the integral on the third math display block.)

Comment: Please use something like $\frak E$ or $\frak O$, or revert back to $E$ and $O$ as $\Bbb E$ denotes expectation, for example.

Answer (score 18):

A famous example of a decomposition in odd and even functions is given by *[Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)*
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{e^{iz}}&\color{blue}{=}\color{blue}{\cos z+i\sin z}\\
&=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}+\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2}\qquad\qquad z\in\mathbb{C}\\
\end{align*}
which is used in many applications.

Answer (score 17):

The answer by KCd mentions in passing what I'll talk about, but I'll elaborate on it: the short answer is *Fourier analysis*.

Splitting a function into odd and even components is an extremely useful problem-solving technique when working with the *Fourier transform*, and the associated *Fourier series*. A function that is purely even or purely odd is easier to find the Fourier transform/series of.

That may seem like a niche topic, but Fourier analysis is one of the most powerful and widely used mathematical techniques. You cannot go far into any STEM field without encountering it, and so making Fourier analysis easier is more significant than you might think.

There is a wealth of knowledge on the internet about what Fourier analysis is and how it works, so I won't reiterate it here. I've found [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spUNpyF58BY) as a good introduction to the topic.